# Scroll bar freezing issue in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I have an MVC project written with JQuery. There is a modal in this project that opens other pages with an iframe inside. My problem is that when the iframe is closed, I can scroll the page with the mouse wheel or scroll bar. But when the iframe is opened, the page freezes when I try to scroll with the scroll bar. The freezing passes when I scroll with the mouse wheel. What could be the reason?

I have reviewed the code and there is nothing in the JQuery events that could cause this. The library we are using to open the modal is not causing it either, because the dropdown scroll bar can freeze as well. I have suspicions that it could be caused by CSS, but I don't know where to look because there are so many CSS files.

Comment: I examined large CSS files and found that the problem is caused by ::-webkit-scrollbar. I will look into what to apply as a solution and I need support on this.